# Dynamic form fields with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for a solution/best practice for the following issue.

I have a page with an HTML form with one dropdown list and a submit button. Underneath of the dropdown box is an empty space that I would like to populate with form inputs based on the selected value in the dropdown box. Im thinking this can be done in JavaScript but I would much prefer a PHP/client side solution if possible.

Example HTML:

```
<form name="initialdropdown" action="#" method="post">
    <select name="action">
    <option value="default">--select--</option>
    <option value="a">Option 1</option>
    <option value="b">Option 2</option>
    <option value="c">Option 3</option>
    <option value="d">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

I've explored calling this php script from the form action:

```
    <?php

    $getOption = $_POST['action'];
    $addUrl = $getOption.".php";

    include $addUrl;
    header("Location: htmlpage.php");

    ?>
```

and then create several different php files (a.php,b.php,c.php, etc. In each of the files then including the HTML form that I would like to echo out wrapped in a function, and including the function in the main HTML page. I do not feel comfortable that this is a good way to do it. Can anyone shed some light on the best way to go about this?

Comment: I think you can trust your feelings here. However I don't really understand your question. For example it's not clear what is inside these `a`-`d.php` files? Why do you redirect after including those?

Comment: This code seems prone to remote code injection and xss

Comment: sorry for not being clear. a-d.php files each include 1 function that echos the new HTML form that I would like to display under the initial dropdown. I redirect because the form action calls to another php script which redirects off of the main HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display something on the HTML form that updates as you pick different options, JavaScript is the natural choice because you don't have to go and make requests to the server which means moving around data and waiting for responses.  JavaScript can simply change the page as many times as you want while the user interacts with the page.

However, if you are dead set on generating whatever you want to display on that form with PHP, you could have PHP output the display information to the page right into the JavaScript.  Then the JavaScript displays this data from PHP.  Or, you can use an AJAX call to PHP to request the data to display each time a different option is chosen.

**update**

Given your latest comment, you could very easily set up more form options without using PHP.  In the HTML set up all the various form options you might want to show, but hide the optional parts with CSS.  Then reveal each section as needed with a little JavaScript.  jQuery can make this even easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and then your update. I was avoiding JavaScript because I have little knowledge in that area. I think the CSS solution you mentioned will be very easy to implement, and I found a quick tutorial that will help me create the JS. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you don't feel comfortable with JavaScript, check out jQuery - it is a JavaScript library that adds a lot of really useful and cross browser compatible features, and it does lots of awesome things using CSS selectors.  Hiding a div with the id `hideme` is as easy as `$("#hideme").hide();`.  I found the basics came easily and I use it all the time.  Check it out, jquery.com